# Moodle - how to add pages/items in navigation bar

Tags: navigation, html, moodle

Hey I just started using moodle and the first problem is: how to I add pages e.g. About us , Contact us.

Do I have too add it manually? Where do I have too change any settings? I tried looking for "Create web page" but I did not find anything.

I am using version 2.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should make them manually, it's not as straightforward as in other CMS like Wordpress.

First, you have to create some php files that includes the common parts of a [Moodle web page](http://moodle21customizations.blogspot.it/2012/02/create-empty-page-for-moodle.html).

As an example, create a file named `about.php` and place it in the root of your Moodle installation (the php code is taken from the tutorial cited above and slightly adapted):

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

$PAGE->set_context(get_system_context());
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');
$PAGE->set_title("About page");
$PAGE->set_heading("About");
$PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/about.php');


echo $OUTPUT->header();

// Actual content goes here
echo "Hello World";

echo $OUTPUT->footer();

?>
```

If you have your Moodle at `http://moodle-example.org`, your about page would be located at `http://moodle-example.org/about.php`.

If you'd like to, you can create a [custom menu](http://www.moodlenews.com/2013/creating-custom-menus-in-moodle/) inserting the path of your newly created page.

Go to *Site administration » Appearance » Themes » Theme settings*. On the *Custom menu items* field, insert:

```
About us|http://moodle-example.org/about.php
```

Save and you'll see a menu containing a link to your newly created page.

Comment: Awesome answer @franzlorenzon. But problem is that `http://moodle-example.org/about.php` is accessible only for logged-in users. Anonymous users not able to access this. How to do this so that anonymous user can also access this url.

Comment: @NishantPandya I think that's a moodle configuration issue. Go to: Settings → Site administration → Security → Site policies. On that page, disable  “Force users to login”.

Comment: @Pacerier what theme are you using? Not everyone supports the feature. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Theme_settings#Custom_menu_items).

Comment: @franzlorenzon, It's an older version. `$version = 2007101524`. There's no "custom menu items" here. What are the options for older version?